# Matlab `imread` is reading in some images as all-zeros

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am using Matlab's **`imread`** to read in images, but about half get **read in as all-zeros, even though they are not all-black images** (I can view them fine in Finder).

The images that fail vary in their:

- file extension (PNG, JPG)
- colorspace (RGB, Gray)
- color profile (sRGB IEC61966-2.1, Calibrated RGB Colorspace, Generic Gray Gamma 2.2 Profile)

However, I have success reading in other PNG and JPG images in RGB and Gray colorspaces. I don't have any instances of successful reads of an sRGB IEC61966-2.1 color profile, although again, not all images that fail have this profile. **I can't see any pattern of file extension, colorspace, etc. that distinguishes that fail from the ones that are read in successfully.**

I have tried the following:

- `[img, map, alpha] = imread('fname.png');`. In all cases this produces all-zero matrices for img, map, and alpha.
- making the file extension explicit, e.g. `imread('fname.png', 'png');`. The result is the same.

I am running Matlab 2019b on macOS Catalina.

Any suggestions for what might be causing some images to fail and for how to import them successfully?

Comment: Can you share a couple of said images so we can also test? Also; have you tried explicitly converting them to double? Also, have you tried to use imshow instead of imagesc to see if there are any values (unless you are already seeing the read matrix variable).

Comment: I've inspected the matrix directly and determined that it is all-zeros. `im2double` converts the all-zero matrix to another all-zero matrix. Here are two example images that aren't getting read in properly: http://clipart-library.com/images/AcbK5pRoi.png, https://silhouettegarden.com/files/images/torch-silhouette-thumbnail.png.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images you linked contain an alpha transparency channel so simply reading using `imread()` will not return the image data. You need to read the image using additiona parameters [as defined on the help page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html):

`[imRGB, map, alpha] = imread('AcbK5pRoi.png');`

where the `imRGB` will contain the RGB image and the `Alpha` will contain the transparency data. 
You can use the `imRGB` variable as a normal image.

Comment: Ok, it's interesting that reading in that way does seem to work for the two examples I linked to. However, there are still others for which it does not (hence my original note that returning [img, map, and alpha] did not work). For example, http://image.spreadshirtmedia.com/image-server/v1/designs/10177614%2Cwidth=200%2Cheight=200 and https://www.shareicon.net/data/256x256/2015/10/19/658401_music_512x512.png continue to be all-zero.

Comment: So i just checked the images in irfanview. The images do not contain any RGB information in the channels, but they only have an alpha channel with data. Dont know why that is so; but the images were generated that way from the source.